# Issues with Mac OS X pinging

Tags: mac-osx, ping

I am trying to ping to IP's and host addresses, and this is the result,

I am not sure this is a error but I am attempting to use a vpn and I can't get it to work. Pinging the IP should be working but as a test this is what I get

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
```

I am no expert in this, but I think this looks wrong.

I am using 10.6.1 OS X

Answer (score 2):

That means your ping isn't getting to the remote machine. This could mean the VPN isn't allowing ICMP packets, or firewalls on the remote end are blocking them.

Can you ping machines on your local network? IE:

```
ping 127.0.0.1
ping 192.168.1.1
ping google.com
```

As an example this is what I get on my OS X machine when pinging google.com:

```
Calcifer:~ jbudde$ ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.67.100): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 74.125.67.100: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=56.669 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.67.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=58.486 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.67.100: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=55.123 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.67.100: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=55.258 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 55.123/56.384/58.486/1.356 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. [Josh Budde asked](https://serverfault.com/questions/73848/issues-with-mac-os-x-pinging/73862#73862) "Can you ping machines on your local network?". In my case, when connected to the VPN server, I could ping devices in the local network but I could not ping to the internet.

Then I found [this thread in the Apple Discussion forums](http://discussions.info.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=7760241) where, at the bottom, it says

> What I did, is adding "localnets" in the Search Domains section under Client information of the VPN service configuration.

I have done that too and now I can ping everywhere. I still don't manage to be able to open any website when I have all traffic going through the VPN, but this seems like one step forward.

Not sure this applies to your problem, but it might be worth a try.

PS: now I see this is 1 year old.. well, it might be useful for someone else.